# I cannot implement Text to Speech in my Unity project for Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, text-to-speech

I was trying to implement a simple Text to Speech(TTS) feature in my mobile app to Speak the text in a TextMeshPro when a button is clicked. I was trying to implement it by  using the Android Native Text-to-Speech API. For that I used TTS implementation from this plugin files from - https://github.com/khanhuitse05/speech-and-text-unity-ios-android/commit/ba633ed2e253fbc66218995eae8b45f6931f4c3d. I have copied all the required files(just TTS file and not of STT) and have setup all according to the video.

When I build the project it builds without any warnings or errors, but the TTS functionality does not works. So, what should I do Or is the any another simpler way to achieve this ?

Comment: Hi, please dont expect people to watch videos and play detective on what you did, or maybe didnt do.  [mcve] please.  Please also include what actually happens.. what you have debugged and found

Comment: @BugFinder extremely sorry for that, I have edited the question and tried to describe the question. Actually I was not understanding how to describe the question. I want to know how can I implement a Text to Speech feature in Unity Android Project. Thanks for your advice.